# How to Customize Colors for Different Series in Dual-Axis Chart?

Tags: visualization

I have a dual-axis chart consisting of a line graph and a bar graph. There can be multiple lines in the line graph and multiple bars in the bar graph.
In a dual-axis chart consisting of both line and bar graphs, how freely define the colors and other details for each bar and line?